# Python - convert list in json file

Tags: python, json

I have in a list lot of data with many occurence like this for example :

```
my_list1 = ['test1', 'testA', 'test1', 'test1','test1','test1','test1','test1', 'testIJJSI', 'testIJJSI''testIJJSI''testIJJSI', 'testA.............]
```

How can I transform this data into JSON file to have something like that :

```
{ 
  "name file": ..., 
  "test1": [ 
      {
          "nb_occurence ": ..., 
          "percent % ":...,
          "catégorie" :....
   ] 
  "testA": [ 
      {
          "nb_occurence ": ..., 
          "percent % ":...,
          "catégorie" :....
   ] 
}
```

Comment: did you try   `json.dumps()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I think I'm understanding: You have a list of elements. You want to calculate a number of statistics about each element and write those statistics to a JSON file where each element name (e.g. "test1", "testA") is a key whose value is a mapping of "statistic_name": value.

Here's how you might do it.

1. Define a function for each statistic you wish to generate, for each unique element in `my_list`.
2. Define a function that generates a collection of statistics for a unique element in `my_list`. Let's call it `gen_stats()` and say it takes argument `element`.
3. Create a dictionary in which keys are the unique elements in `my_list` and the values are the statistics generated by calling `gen_stats()` on each unique element.
4. using the standard library `json`, write a json file from the dictionary.

Here's some elliptical example code:

```
import json

def count(element):
    ...

def percent(element):
    ...

def gen_stats(element):
    return {
        "count": count(element),
        "percent": percent(element),
        ...
    }

unique_elements = set(my_list)

my_dict = { element: gen_stats(element) for element in unique_elements }

with open("file/path/here.json", "wt") as f:
    json.dump(my_dict, f)
```